# xubuntu 12.04 can only log on to graphical interface with guest account

Tags: xubuntu, login

When i log on to my main account on xubuntu 12.04 the screen goes black after a few seconds and i have to do <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type "shutdown" to log out. I can accsess my account through terminal only with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> but the only way to accsess a graphical interface is by logging on to the guest account. How do i fix this?

EDIT: Nevermind, updated grub and now everything works.